# How to count the java process of specific user in ps aux

Tags: linux

Currently am executing this

```
ps aux | grep java
```

It is returning

```
root 4589 <some process>
user1 4218 <some process1>
user1 4248 <some process2>
user1 4258 <some process3>
```

Here how we can count the processes which is running by "user1"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit more direct and should do what you want:

```
pgrep -u user1 java
```

Comment: Thanks, It is returning the process id of the particular user

Got the count of the process by using `pgrep -u user1 java | wc -w`